# Count of row frequency in a specific range

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a database `df_final` with many rows (3000) and 4 columns. 
To get a count the number of times that each number occurs in a specific column ,  I'm using this:

```
counts <- ddply(df_final, .(round(df_final$`Nº HB (1-8)`)), nrow)
names(counts) <- c("HB", "% ")
```

Output looks like:

```
1    4    1      
2    5    34
3    6    470
4    7    1886
5    8    609
```

However, what I really need is the frequency of numbers between a range, for example (0-8).

Output should look like:

```
1        1    0
2        2    0
3        3    0
4        4    0 
5        5    34
6        6    470
7        7    1886
8        8    609
```

Comment: Without showing the input data, it is not clear.  You can do `table(factor(round(df_final$"Nº HB (1-8)"), levels = 1:8)`

Comment: @akrun yes, that works!. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` after specifying the `levels`

```
table(factor(round(df_final$"Nº HB (1-8)"), levels = 1:8)
```